# How to get subscription name of azure resource group

Tags: azure, shell

Is there a way to get the subscription name from azure resource group?

I tried below API but it gives only subscription id:

```
curl -H Metadata:True "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-08-01
```

or is there any way to get subscription name from it's `id`?

Answer (score 0):

The subscription name is not a property of the Resource Group, so there is no direct REST API for that. But once you have the subscription ID, use this API for the sub details such as its display name go: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/get

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}?api-version=2016-06-01
```